# sql server 2005 developer edition

Tags: sql-server, installation

I installed sql server 2005 developer edition on my pc.
I am not able to see server in management studio.
I installed default instace as an installation option.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Start->All Programs->Microsoft SQL Server 2005->Configuration Tools-> SQL Server Configuration Manager

Once the program is open click SQL Server 2005 Services. Look for an entry named SQL Server (YOUR INSTANCE NAME HERE).  Copy  and try to go into Managment Studio and login as localhost\YOUR INSTANCE NAME HERE and see what happens. This assumes you are on the same machine the database is on.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to register the database in the management studio. The first icon under 'object explorer' is 'Connect Object Explorer'. Click that and you should be able to find your database server in the popup window.

If you find that you can not find the database server in the drop downlist, you can click the options button at the bottom of the dialog box and bring up the 'Connection Properties'. Click on the 'Connect to database dropdown' and then 'Browse server'. You should now be able to browse you network and find all SQL databases that functioning on the network.

If you do not find the database server, you might want to check that it is running and/or the machine that it is installed on is connected to your network.

Good luck.

Comment: you are not getting my problem.
I had already click on connect object explorer. I can not see any server name in new pop up window.

Comment: You put "." or LocalHost for the server name.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps way too foolish of an answer, but did you authenicate? File>Connect Object Explorer then in the "connection to server dialo"g box use "localhost" as server name, authenication = "sql server authentication", user name = "sa", password is equal to the sa password you were asked to create on installation.

If you have done this, and are attempting to connect from a diffent box then the installation box, usually you have not turned on remote connections in the surface area configuration tools.